# How to serve static html content page in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm starting an embedded tomcat via `spring-boot` and want to serve a static `index.html` page as part of a running application.

But the following does not work:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HMyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}


@RestController 
public class HomeContoller {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}

src/main/resources/static/index.html
```

Result: when I call `localhost:8080`, I just see the word "index", but not my html page. Why?

Comment: That's because `@RestController` is a meta-annotation for `@Controller` and `ResponseBody`, meaning it writes "index" to the response input stream. You should use `@Controller` instead so that "index" will be resolved as a view name.

Comment: Omg you're right, absolutely. I probably was confused as developing a `@RestController` side by side. Anyways I'm now getting the following exception using `@Controller`: `javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'`. It neither works returning `index.html` instead.

Comment: I think the view name should be `static/index.html`

Comment: Neither `static/index` nor `static/index.html` works.

Comment: See my answer below, I solved it.

Comment: .@orid has the right answer. If you pasted the login method into an existing controller and that controller has `@RestController` for all methods, then it'll try to return *content*. Move the method to a new controller and annotate it `@Controller` instead so that a *view* will be generated.

Comment: Nothing is working for me. and i am getting There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My fault: I had an additional class with `@EnableWebMvc` annotation. This somehow messed up the spring-boot autoconfiguration. I removed it and now it works returning `index.html`.

Answer (score 11):

For me this worked, i am sure there is a better way ( like without .html ).

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index.html";
}
```

Comment: if your use the JSP page (index.jsp) Then you can use return "index".

Comment: This works, however if I change the Controller to a specific mapping it says 404. For example, Controller mapping: @Controller @RequestMapping("/user)" and the Method mapping: @RequestMapping("/{id}"), then I get a 404 error. It only works for the request mapping "/".

Comment: If you need json data as a response you should use the mapping in a @RestController class. 
If you need a view then it get's complicated a bit. What do you want to do?
And usually if you put the static resources under a [resources/static folder structure it works automatically because of spring boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).
Also if you use /{id} you should have in the method params a @PathVariable("id") so it works, not sure if you left that out on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ModelAndView` in order to serve static HTML content in spring boot.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView home()
{
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("index");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

application.properties:-

spring.mvc.view.suffix = .html

HTML File : - src/main/resources/static/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Thats because of @RestController annotation, just removing this annotation works for me.