# REST Service doesn't consume data from form

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jersey

I have written two simple functions, GET and POST, for consume data from form. Unfortunately when I'm submitting this form, instead of get response, form with empty fields is again displayed. It changes URL address from *http://localhost:8080/example* to *http://localhost:8080/example/?version=5.4&id=1*. What is missing for displaying correct response?

```
@Component
@Path("/example")
public class ExampleService {
   @GET
   public String message() {
       return "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
              "<html>\n" +
              "<body>\n" +
              "\n" +
              "<form>\n" +
              "    Version\n" +
              "    <input type=\"text\" name=\"version\" value=\"\">\n" +
              "    Id\n" +
              "    <input type=\"text\" name=\"id\" value=\"\">\n" +
              "    <input type=\"submit\">\n" +
              "</form>\n" +
              "\n" +
              "</body>\n" +
            "</html>";
   }

   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
   @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
   public Response createFromForm(
        @FormParam("version") String version,
        @FormParam("id") String id
   ) {
      return Response.status(201).entity(version).build();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your form is submitting the results as a url (GET).

add
method="POST" to your form

ie:

```
<form method="POST">
// other parts here
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah! Of course I have overlooked it... I have one more question, how can I inside this spring boot index.html file configure?

Comment: i did not fully get your 2nd question. but anyway try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876389/how-to-serve-static-html-content-page-in-spring-boot)