# Springboot won't load my HTML page using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Already been on these topics but haven't worked for me:

1. [Topic1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876389/how-to-serve-static-html-content-page-in-spring-boot) No `@EnableWebMvc` annotation in my project

This is the dependency i used for `Thymeleaf`:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

- My new Controller named `ViewController`

```java
package myrest.Viewcontroller;

//Imports

@Controller
public class ViewController {


    public static String uploadDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/uploads";
    @RequestMapping("/uploadendpoint")
    public String uploadPage(Model model)
    {
        return "uploadView";
    }

}
```

- The `HTML` named `uploadView.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action = "/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Files"></input>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

- Project's structure:

[image]

My Comments: I'm still getting a **Whitelabel Error Page** , at `localhost:8082/uploadendpoint`

**Edit1:**

My `@SpringBootApplication` class

```java
package myrest;

import java.io.File;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import myrest.Viewcontroller.ViewController;
import myrest.controller.MainController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RemoteapiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new File(ViewController.uploadDirectory).mkdir();
        SpringApplication.run(RemoteapiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

`application.properties` file:

```
server.port:8082
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=15MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=15MB
```

Server's `logs`

```
2020-01-07 14:37:56.708  INFO 9317 --- [  restartedMain] myrest.RemoteapiApplication              : Starting RemoteapiApplication on ZenbookPro with PID 9317 (/home/pihill/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.9.RELEASE/remoteapi/target/classes started by pihill in /home/pihill/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.9.RELEASE/remoteapi)
2020-01-07 14:37:56.708  INFO 9317 --- [  restartedMain] myrest.RemoteapiApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-01-07 14:37:56.770  WARN 9317 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry  : The MBean registry cannot be disabled because it has already been initialised
2020-01-07 14:37:56.781  INFO 9317 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8082 (http)
2020-01-07 14:37:56.782  INFO 9317 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-01-07 14:37:56.782  INFO 9317 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
2020-01-07 14:37:56.784  INFO 9317 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-01-07 14:37:56.784  INFO 9317 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 75 ms
2020-01-07 14:37:56.801  INFO 9317 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-01-07 14:37:56.814  INFO 9317 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-01-07 14:37:56.820  INFO 9317 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8082 (http) with context path ''
2020-01-07 14:37:56.820  INFO 9317 --- [  restartedMain] myrest.RemoteapiApplication              : Started RemoteapiApplication in 0.119 seconds (JVM running for 2930.389)
2020-01-07 14:37:56.821  INFO 9317 --- [  restartedMain] .ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener : Condition evaluation unchanged
2020-01-07 14:37:59.725  INFO 9317 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-01-07 14:37:59.726  INFO 9317 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-01-07 14:37:59.727  INFO 9317 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

Whitelabel error page:

[image]

Comment: Remove the thymeleaf dependency and instead use the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`. check your logs for errors (or at leats post the result). Add your `application.properties` content, as well as your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

Comment: @M.Deinum nothing's changed, no errors, i will post them asap

Comment: Please check your logs (and add them as well as the error page you get).

Comment: sure, the error is that i have not mapped /error (404)

Comment: Do you have spring starter web dependency too?

Comment: Enable debug/trace logging and check your logs. That 404 is for the `/error` but the underlying error you have is different.

Comment: @AK47 yes i do have

Comment: Enable debug logging and navigate to the page again and check the logs

Comment: should i post the `negative` or `positive` matches? got some unconditional classes too, exclusions:`none`

Comment: `devtools` does not fully restart your  application does it? i just restarted it the normal way and it works

Comment: @M.Deinum you are correct thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like M.Deinum said. You are using Spring Boot so get the benefits from using the starter packages. In the spring-boot-starter-thymleaf package are more dependencies included than just in the org.thymeleaf 3.0.11.RELEASE.

Replace this in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

with this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then it works like charming.

Comment: yes i restarted it the normal way from the IDE , i though `devtools` restart the whole application... works!

Comment: After dependency changes or changes to the pom.xml the project needs to be rebuild. So great it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Add your Html file in src/main/resource/templates/test.html(select any name)
Then add this with html tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Create a Controller to open your html file:

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

@GetMapping("/OpenTestFile")
    public String OpenTestFile(Model model) {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Open with this Url:

```
http://localhost:8082/OpenTestFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Some times the IDE your using like intelliJ community version will not support MVC,  please check with your IDE supports the requirements

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I suggest you convert it to a comment instead, thank you though!