# Can I do one GetMapping for all pages in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a question about `@GetMapping` in Spring Boot.

If I have 20 static web pages as `.html` files. Could I use only one `@GetMapping` to get every single pages?

For example:

```
@GetMapping("/{static_webpages}")
public String getWeb() { return "{static_webpages}";}
```

Then, when the path becomes `/page1`, it will get page 1, and so on.

Comment: static html pages, images, javascript and css files can be served as `static content` and do not require you to write a controller. It just needs some configuration. Example [how-to can be found here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources)

Comment: Yes, you can have `GetMapping` if you are not going with configuration, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876389/how-to-serve-static-html-content-page-in-spring-boot#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20ModelAndView%20in%20order%20to%20serve,application.properties%3A-%20spring.mvc.view.suffix%20%3D.html%20HTML%20File%20%3A%20-%20src%2Fmain%2Fresources%2Fstatic%2Findex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Extracting the name of the webpage from the URL.

By adding a parameter to your method and annotating it with the `@PathVariable` annotation you can extract the name of the webpage.

```java
    @GetMapping("/{static_webpage}")
    public String getWeb(@PathVariable("static_webpage") String webpage) {
        ...
    }
```

### Return the webpage instead of returning a string

You probably don't want to return the content of the webpage in form of a string.
By  using the `ModelAndView` object as a return type of your method, your method will return a proper webpage.

```java
    @GetMapping("/{static_webpage}")
    public ModelAndView getWeb(@PathVariable("static_webpage") String webpage) {
        ...
    }
```

Now we can construct the `ModelAndView` object to redirect to the given webpage.

```java
    @GetMapping("/{static_webpage}")
    public ModelAndView getWeb(@PathVariable("static_webpage") String static_webpage) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("webpages/" + static_webpage);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

In this example the static webpages were saved in the `resources/static/webpages` directory for the sake of grouping them into one single directory.
If you don't want to group them into one directory you would just store them at `resources/static/`, although you would have to be careful, because the `ModelAndView` object would then try to load its own rest endpoint, which would result in an error.

### [OPTIONAL] Removing the needed html extension in the url

With the `spring.mvc.view.suffix` property in your `application.properties` you can provide a suffix, that is appended to every ModelAndView webpage you create.

```yaml
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .html
```

This means that instead of having to access the webpage `/myexamplepage.html`
you would only have to access `/myexamplepage`.

#### Resources

- [ModelAndView](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-model-model-map-model-view)
- [@PathVariable](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-pathvariable)